# How do I add content to the Cast Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, chromecast

I am creating a data-centric application and allow the user to cast information to the Chromecast.

I am using the CCL from Github to aide in implementation (e.g. restoring sessions)

But how do I add content to the dialog that is shown when you click the cast button?

Currently, by default, it just shows the CC device name, a volume slider and the disconnect button.

I'd like to show what type of information is currently being shown (in place of what video or music might be playing, if you had that type of application)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CCL, it does provide that for you, see its documentation and the CastVideos-android sample app. If you want to do it yourself, take a look at the package com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.dialog.video in CCL to see how it can be done.

Comment: I was unable to locate it in the docs. Just looked through the sample on github and can't see anything in there either tbh. Looking at the actual library code gives some insight, but it'd be nice to see a working example, not based on video or audio

Comment: CastVideos-android is a working example that uses CCL. Also, the package I mentioned has classes that you need, so I am not sure what more you expect to see.